# Running python script in parallel with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am managing 6 machines, or more, at AWS with Ansible. Those machines must run a python script that runs forever (the script has a while True).

I call the python script via command: python3 script.py

But just 5 machines run the script, the others doesn't. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

(Before the script call everything works fine for all machines like echo, ping, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I already found the awnser.

The fork in ansible restrict to 5 machines as default. You must add an fork to the configuration file with a greater number, but your machine with Ansible must have power to manage that.

I'll let the question because to me was pretty hard to find the awnser.